# Intellij not resolving the maven dependenciess

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I had some issue with my old project. So deleted the old one and tried setting up from scratch again.

this is a maven project and I am using Intellij 2021 version.

I cloned the repo using Intellij - get from VCS option.

added maven framework support.

Did Maven-> reload project step.

Still I see 55 dependency errors as attached.

[image]

one such sample dependency error out of 55 is below

Cannot resolve org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.5.RELEASE

Already tried below steps

Invalidate the cache and restart IntelliJ

Delete the .idea folder and the .iml files

Delete my maven repository folder

below is the settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository

  <localRepository>.m2/repository</localRepository>-->

    <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

    <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->

    <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
    <pluginGroups>
        <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

    <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
    <proxies>
        <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>xx</username>
      <password>xx</password>
      <host>xx</host>
      <port>xx</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
    </proxies>

    <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
    <servers>
        <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>xx</username>
      <password>xx</password>
    </server>
    -->

        <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
     <!-- Artifactory access -->
        
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <username>xx</username>
            <password>xx</password>
        </server>
       
-->
    </servers>

    <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
   |
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
   | it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred
   | server for that repository.
   |-->
    <mirrors>
        <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://xx</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
    </mirrors>

    <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is
   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a
   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
   |       variables for plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->
    <profiles>
        <!-- profile
     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
     | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
     | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
     |
     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
     | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
     | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
     | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
     |
     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->

        <!--
     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
     | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
     | might hypothetically look like:
     |
     | ...
     | <plugin>
     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
     |
     |   <configuration>
     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
     |   </configuration>
     | </plugin>
     | ...
     |
     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
     |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
     |
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
          <properties>
            <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
          </properties>
        </profile>
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>clean</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>http://xx</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://xx</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>plugins-release</name>
                    <url>http://xx</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>plugins-release</name>
                    <url>http://xx</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <properties>
                <!-- URL to SonarQube server. -->
                                
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <!-- activeProfiles
     | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
     |
    <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
      <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    -->
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProviderToolsJavaTestAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha.${build.number}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ProviderToolsJavaTestAutomation</name>

    <properties>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <rest-assured.version>4.0.0</rest-assured.version>
        <javatestautomation.version>[1.7.3,)</javatestautomation.version>`enter code here`
        <testng.version>7.0.0</testng.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <build.number>1</build.number>
        <!--SonarQube-->
        <sonar.exclusions>target/**</sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.login>xx</sonar.login>
        <sonar.exclusions>target/**</sonar.exclusions>

        <ojdbc.version>1.0</ojdbc.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.1.4</postgresql.version>
        <spring.framework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                            <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                            <Implementation-Version>${build.number}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>uber-ProviderToolsJavaTestAutomation-1.0-alpha</finalName>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/license/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>License</exclude>
                                <exclude>Notice</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--Start - Use this to group main\java and test\java classes into the same jar. Used to run tests from a single uber jar-->
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>bin</testOutputDirectory>
        <!--End-->
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What happen when you do `mvn install` from terminal/command prompt?

Comment: Yes, please provide the result of `mvn clean install` command in terminal. Also try latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download - as there was one related issue fixed.

Comment: First follow conventions which means remove: `<outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>` and `<testOutputDirectory>bin</testOutputDirectory>` that will make your life easier....